# Sfumature dell'aggettivo "stringato" usato per descrivere il modo di esprimersi

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel vocabolario Treccani appare questa accezione del vocabolo ["stringato"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stringato/):

> **2.** fig. Breve e conciso, ridotto all’essenziale ma al tempo stesso esauriente, detto di scritti, discorsi e sim.: *una relazione, un’esposizione s.; un’argomentazione s. e rigorosa; uno stile secco e s.; seguitava a parlare ... senza misura e in modo forse non troppo s.* (Landolfi).

Dunque, se ho capito bene questa spiegazione, l'aggettivo "stringato" può avere sia una connotazione positiva (per esempio, *"un’argomentazione stringata e rigorosa"*) sia un'accezione negativa (come in *"uno stile secco e stringato"*). È così? Potreste aiutarmi a capire le diverse sfumature di questo aggettivo facendo altri esempi?

Comment: Ernest Hemingway ed Harlan Ellison forse non concorderebbero sul fatto che "uno stile secco e stringato" é necessariamente una cosa negativa :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La definizione del *Treccani* è corretta. Come si può comprendere, però, la stringatezza è una virtú relativa: imprescindibile in alcuni casi, insoddisfacente in altri. Si vedano questi due esempi giornalistici:

> La mattinata l’hanno trascorsa leggendo il documento congressuale,
>   nella nuova stesura supervisionata dallo stesso Natta: un testo più
>   agile e **stringato**, con una parte politica generale di una ventina
>   di cartelle e una serie di schede programmatiche per altre quaranta,
>   in tutto meno di 70 pagine. [*[La Repubblica](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/1985/11/29/77-saggi-del-pci-esaminano.html)*, 29 novembre 1985]
>
> Del cambio al vertice non si è parlato fino a ieri (anche se
>   l’istituto ne aveva dato notizia con uno **stringato** comunicato) quando
>   è stato presentato il 48° Rapporto sulla situazione sociale del Paese,
>   il fiore all'occhiello del Censis. [*[La Repubblica](http://ricerca.repubblica.it/repubblica/archivio/repubblica/2014/12/06/de-rita-mio-figlio-direttore-curriculum-adeguato04.html)*, 6 dicembre 2014]

Nell’esempio dato dal *Treccani*, *stringato* in «uno stile secco e stringato» *non* ha una connotazione necessariamente negativa. Anzi, è vero piú spesso il contrario: sono gli aggettivi *ampolloso*, *barocco*, riferiti allo stile, a caricarsi di un’accezione negativa.

Answer (score 4):

Ritengo che il termine: "stringato" non abbia alcuna connotazione positiva o negativa. Lo considero un sinonimo di: "sintetico", da cui può essere sostituito senza che si perda alcuna sfumatura di significato. Non riesco a vedere (forse è un mio difetto) alcuna connotazione negativa nell'esempio che hai portato: "uno stile secco e stringato"; solo il contesto può dirci se la caratteristica della comunicazione (essere stringata) è o meno *appropriata*.

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente considero "stringato" un sinonimo di "schietto". L'accezione positiva o negativa può dipendere molto dal contesto in cui viene inserito.

Per esempio, se dico che una persona ha dei modi di fare molto stringati, posso intendere che quella persona non è di molte parole, quindi non molto socievole (attribuendo a stringato un'accezione negativa) o posso intendere che è una persona molta pratica, schietta (quindi attribuendogli un'accezione positiva).

Comment: Secondo il vocabolario Treccani, però, ["schietto"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/schietto/) non ha lo stesso significato.

Comment: Esempi in cui *stringato* è usato con lo stesso significato di *schietto*?

Comment: Io l'ho sempre usato per indicare qualcosa di estremamente pratico, diretto, conciso; Il suo significato come "Puro, privo di contaminazioni o mescolanze" l'ho appena scoperto!